# Adding and averaging a set of columns depending on the value of a secondary column in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, sentiment-analysis

I have a dataset which has the following values:

```
LabelA    PositiveA     NegativeA    LabelB    PositiveB     NegativeB    LabelC    PositiveC  NegativeC  Final_Label
  1          .60           .40         0          .30           .70         1          .9          .1         1
  0          .1            .9          0          .49           .51         0          .3          .7         0
  0          .34           .66         1          .87           .13         1          .90         .1         1
```

Final_label would be 1 if majority of Labels (LabelA, LabelB and LabelC) would be 1 and vice-versa.

I want to calculate a column called "Polarity" which has the following defination:

1. If Final_label = 1, Polarity is the mean of all the "PositiveA/B/C" whose Label was also 1
2. If Final_label = 0, Polarity is the mean of all the "NegativeA/B/C" whose label was also 0

For example in the above dataset, Polarity would have the following value:

```
Polarity
.75           (adding and taking average of PositiveA and PositiveC)
.7033         (adding and taking average of NegativeA and Negativeb and NegativeC)
.885          (adding and taking average of PositiveB and PositiveC)
```

How do I implement this in python? Over here I have shown 3 columns, in my dataset I have 7 Label columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my approach with `where` and `mask`:

```
# filter the labels, positives, negatives:
labels = df.filter(regex='Label\w').eq(1).values
positives = df.filter(regex='Positive\w')
negatives = df.filter(regex='Negative\w')

# output
df['Polarity'] = np.where(df['Final_Label'], 
                          positives.where(labels).mean(axis=1), 
                          negatives.mask(labels).mean(axis=1)
                         )

print(df['Polarity'])
```

Output:

```
0    0.750000
1    0.703333
2    0.885000
Name: Polarity, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Never knew Regex is that powerfull!!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a function that can be applied to the dataframe row by row.  When you use the `axis=1` option, x is a row of the dataframe, where column values can be obtained using the column name:

```
def polar(x):
    if x['Final_Label'] == 1:
        return (x['PositiveA'] + x['PositiveB'] + x['PositiveC'])/3
    elif x['Final_Label'] == 0:
        return (x['NegativeA'] + x['NegativeB'] + x['NegativeC'])/3
    else:
        raise ValueError("Final_Label invalid")
df['Polarity'] = df.apply(polar,axis = 1)
```